# How to make a page accessible by two urls for seo purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, seo

We currently have a page that has this url: `/tires?product_subtype=8`. The page content is a tires list filtered by a specific product subtype. For SEO purposes, we also need the page to be accessible via this url: `/lawn-and-garden`.

Is there an easy way to do this? We're using Ruby on Rails framework and Nginx.

We will be doing this on lots of pages:

```
/tires?product_subtype=1 - /industrial-tires
/tires?product_subtype=2 - /commercial-tires
etc...
```

Comment: I think you will need to test for `params[:product_subtype]` in your controller and redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: @moveson Problem is we also need the pages to be accessible via their original url. We don't want to redirect them to the other url. Example: If user visits `/tires?product_subtype=8` the url will stay the same. If user visits `/lawn-and-garden` the url will also stay the same. No redirects will happen.

Comment: In that case, you just need each controller to render the same view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the routes are performing the same task then route them to the same `controller#action` in `config/routes.rb`.

For example:

```
get 'tires', to: 'welcome#index'
get 'lawn-and-garden', to: 'welcome#index'
```

**UPDATE:**

If I understand you right, then you would like the page to be accessible by both routes `/tires?product_subtype=1` as well as `/industrial-tires`(without query param). We have done something similar on one of our projects, we call these pretty url's as landing pages. I can think of two options to implement these landing pages:

- If you have a fixed number of very few landing pages:

  create an action for each of them which renders corresponding subtype view.

  ```
  def industrial_tires
    ## render view filtered for product_subtype = 1
  end

  def commercial_tires
    ## render view filtered for product_subtype = 2
  end
  ## .... so on
  ```
- If you have many/ variable number of landing pages:

  you will have to create a low priority catch all route and within the mapped action conditionally render specific view based on the slug.

  ```
  get '*path', to: 'tires#landing_page'  ## in routes.rb at the end of the file

  def landing_page
    ## "path" would be equal to industrial-tires or commercial-tires, etc.
    ## conditionally specify view filtered for product_subtype based on path value
  end
  ```

Comment: I think the OP wants to redirect differently depending on the `product_subtype` param.

Comment: That won't work since we have to consider the `product_subtype` querystring parameter.

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco So do you mean that you don't want to pass the same query string parameter to second route but have multiple routes like `industrial-trial` equivalent to `/tires?product_subtype=1`, `commercial-tires` equivalent to ``/tires?product_subtype=2`, etc..?

Comment: @JohnKevinM.Basco I have added an update section to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you route your various categories to a single CategoriesController and create an action for each category.

```
/routes.rb

...
get 'lawn-and-garden', to: 'categories#lawn_and_garden'
get 'industrial-tires', to: 'categories#industrial_tires'
...

/categories_controller.rb

def lawn_and_garden
  params[:product_subtype] = '8'
  @tires = YourTireFilter.search(params)
  render 'tires/index'
end

def industrial_tires
  params[:product_subtype] = '1'
  @tires = YourTireFilter.search(params)
  render 'tires/index'
end
```

Repeat for other URLs.